# 2D array into an object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Essentially, I would like to make:

```
var current = [
    [4, 'socks'],
    [2, 'pants'],
    [1, 'shoes'],
    [5, 'hats']
];
```

Into this:

```
var current = {
    socks: 4,
    pants: 2,
    shoes: 1,
    hats: 5
};
```

Comment: Yes, you can! try with a loop if you haven't yet. If you have and weren't happy with the result, post your code and explain where you have problems

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to iterate through a collection and return a single object then `reduce()` is your tool:

```
var current = [
    [4, 'socks'],
    [2, 'pants'],
    [1, 'shoes'],
    [5, 'hats']];

current.reduce(
   function(m,c) { 
       m[c[1]] = c[0]; 
       return m;
   }, {})

// Object {socks: 4, pants: 2, shoes: 1, hats: 5}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

Answer (score 2):

You can loop through the arrays in the array and add them as properties in the object:

```
var result = {};
for (var i = 0; i < current.length; i++) {
  result[current[i][1]] = current[i][0];
}
```

Demo:

```js
var current = [
    [4, 'socks'],
    [2, 'pants'],
    [1, 'shoes'],
    [5, 'hats']];

var result = {};
for (var i = 0; i < current.length; i++) {
     result[current[i][1]] = current[i][0];
}

// show result in snippet
document.write(JSON.stringify(result));
```

Answer (score 1):

With `[].forEach.call()`:

```js
 var current = [
   [4, 'socks'],
   [2, 'pants'],
   [1, 'shoes'],
   [5, 'hats']
 ];

 var res = {};

 [].forEach.call(current, function(el) {
   res[el[1]] = el[0];
 });

console.log(res);

var html = document.getElementById("result");
result.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(res);
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```